# Highcharts - spider web chart questions

Tags: highcharts

I'm working with Highcharts spider web chart at the moment and wanted to see if I can do the following

- How do I zoom polar charts? (or is it possible?)
- How do I put background-color in each of the segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How do I zoom polar charts? (or is it possible?)**

If you want a zoom like `zoomType` then no. `zoomType` is disabled for polar charts by `highcharts-more.js`. From source:

```
// Disable certain features on angular and polar axes
chart.inverted = false;
chartOptions.chart.zoomType = null;
```

> **How do I put background-color in each of the segment?**

You can use math and `Chart.renderer` to create and fill paths to color the background of the segments. For example you might do it like this:

```
var colors = [ "pink", "yellow", "blue", "red", "green", "cyan", "teal", "indigo" ];    
var parts = 6;

for(var i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
    centerX = chart.plotLeft + chart.yAxis[0].center[0];
    centerY = chart.plotTop + chart.yAxis[0].center[1];
    axisLength = chart.yAxis[0].height;
    angleOffset = -Math.PI/2;
    angleSegment = Math.PI/(parts/2);

    firstPointX = centerX + (axisLength * Math.cos(angleOffset + (angleSegment * i)));
    firstPointY = centerY + (axisLength * Math.sin(angleOffset + (angleSegment * i)));

    secondPointX = centerX + (axisLength * Math.cos(angleOffset + (angleSegment * (i+1))));
    secondPointY = centerY + (axisLength * Math.sin(angleOffset + (angleSegment * (i+1))));                                                                                       

    chart.renderer.path([
        'M', centerX, centerY, 
        'L', firstPointX, firstPointY,
        'L', secondPointX, secondPointY,
        'Z'
    ]).attr({
        fill: colors[i % colors.length],
        'stroke-width': 1,
        'opacity': 1
    }).add();
}
```

As seen in [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/fsf6wjb5/). You just have to match number of categories with the `parts` variable.

Comment: thanks @ondkloss, is there any other form of zooming in? I guess I'm probably thinking I need to change the min and max of the axis...

Comment: That is a good suggestion. Sort of a "fake zoom", but using `chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(min,max)` is at least something.